# How to run tomcat 7 on eclipse helios

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat7, eclipse-wtp

i have **tomcat 7.0.22** and **eclipse Helios 3.6.1**
what **WTP** packages to install so that it will tomcat 7 will work fine with Helios 3.6.1
there are lots of packages in the following URL:

http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates

1. Patches.
2. Patches for tests.
3. Project Provided Components.
4. Web Tools Platform (WTP) 3.1.1.
5. Web Tools Platform SDK (WTP SDK) 3.1.1.
6. Web Tools Platform SDK (WTP SDK) 3.1.2.
7. Web Tools Platform Tests (WTP Tests) 3.1.2.
8. Web Tools Platform Tests (WTP Tests) 3.1.2.

will the WTP plugin be enough, or i have to make **extra configuration** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just download ["Eclipse IDE for Java **EE** developers"](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) (with the **EE**). It contains everything you need for Java EE development, including the WTP, Tomcat server plugins and many more useful plugins.

Comment: Doesn't matter. It changes every year. The key point is that you need the "Java **EE**" version and not the "Java" version without EE. The Java EE version has everything for Java EE development preinstalled/preconfigured in single download.

Comment: i have this version but the helios packages, and it doesn't work fine with tomcat 7.

Comment: You'd need to be more specific about "doesn't work fine". It works fine for me (and likely also the rest of the users). Just ask a new and detailed question if you stucks with Helios + Tomcat 7. Perhaps you're using it wrong or configured it wrong or misinterpreted the (mis)behaviour. I can't tell much based on "doesn't work fine". I can't immediately beam myself over to you in person so that I can see the issue myself.